# How do I add a 'clicked' option to ListBox.Option (Headless UI)

Tags: reactjs

See here, https://headlessui.com/react/listbox#styling-the-active-and-selected-option .
The Listbox.Option only supports active (when you hover over an option) and selected (when an option is selected). How can I add a clicked option to ListBox.Option? In effect, I want to style the option blue background when clicked.